# Just can't connect to MySQL EC2 ubuntu instance remotely

Tags: mysql, networking, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, port

I know there are several threads about this, but I've tried everything and am at my wit's end- I would just like to be able to connect to a MySQL database hosted on EC2.

1. I have added port 3306 to the security group for the instance on EC2.
2. I have removed bind_address (skip-networking is no longer used by default) from the my.cnf file and restarted MySQL. I have also alternatively tried bind_address=(external IP, it starts with 54.) and bind_address=0.0.0.0.
3. UFW status is inactive.
4. *On* the server, running:

   `mysql -u remote-user -p -h MY_EXTERNAL_IP`

works! But it doesn't work from my client, I get:

```
`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'MY_EXTERNAL_IP' (111)`
```

1. I created my current MySQL user with:

   `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'remote-user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

   `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'remote-user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
2. I even ran:

   `sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`

   `sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`

   `sudo iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`
3. Telnet doesn't connect:

   `echo X | telnet -e X MY_EXTERNAL_IP 3306`
   `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

But it does connect to the ssh port:

```
Trying 54.221.103.104...
Connected to 54.221.103.104.
```

and `netstat -a | grep 'mysql'` gives:

```
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                 *:*                     LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20762    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Please, I'm at my wit's end. I just can't figure out what's wrong with this, I've been working on it for hours.

Comment: I am able to connect via telnet to port 3306 at 54.221.103.104? How come you are not?

Comment: Oops, forgot to remove the IP, but I don't really care. Thanks- perhaps my local network is blocking outgoing ports, or something.

Comment: It looks like you did everything right. I would look at your local network to see if its blocking outgoing ports. You could connect via SSH tunnel as well

Answer (score 4):

comment line in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` that says: `bind-address 127.0.0.1` this is the reason, I spend some 20-30 mins to figure out why it happens with disabled firewall :) this line makes Your server to listen only to calls from localhost on this port. Ofcourse You have to restart mysql service after this.

Comment: Telnet is failing hence this won't work in his case. OP already mentioned this in his second point.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, this bind address is located in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf, for anyone scanning through the answers.  Took me forever to discover this.

Answer (score 1):

change the bind address in /etc/mysql/my.cnf  from 127.0.0.1  to 0.0.0.0  has solved my issue and I was able to TELNET remotely on port 3306 without issues.

Also make sure your mysql user is not set only as a localhost mysql user and has the proper privileges.